# how to append two created html elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code

```
   var element1 = document.createElement('div');
   var element2= document.createElement('a');
   element1.append(element2);
```

without using innerHTML I get the error append is not a function???
resolve that????

thank you

Comment: `$('<div />', {html : $('<a />')})`

Comment: use `appendChild` insead of `append`

Comment: Is your intention to make `a` a child of `div`? Or do you  want them to be siblings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a solution to your problem (use `element1.appendChild(element)` with plain DOM elements), but I thought I'd explain some aspects of jQuery that led to your confusion.

**DOM Methods Only**

A DOM object such as what you created with `document.createElement('div');` has DOM methods attached to it.  There are many different DOM methods, but the DOM method for appending a child object is `.appendChild()`, not `.append()` which led to your confusion.  So, as long as you are only using pure DOM objects (no jQuery involved), then you stick to pure DOM methods and use `.appendChild()` as in:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
var element2= document.createElement('a');
element1.appendChild(element2);
```

---

**jQuery Methods Only**

jQuery, creates its own set of methods and those methods are attached to jQuery objects (not to DOM objects).  So, if you create a jQuery object with `$(...)`, then you only use jQuery methods on that object.  On a jQuery object, there is a `.append()` method (which likely led to your confusion).

So, using jQuery, you could have done:

```
var elem1 = $("<div>").append($("<a>"));
```

Or, even just this (I show more complete HTML here for the `<a>` tag):

```
var elem1 = $("<div><a href='http://www.google.com'>Click here</a></div>")
```

---

**Summary**

So, when calling methods, just keep in mind that if your object is a DOM object, then you call DOM methods on it:

```
element1.appendChild(element2);
```

Or, if your object is a jQuery object, then you call jQuery methods on it:

```
var elem1 = $("<div>").append($("<a>"));
```

Or, you can actually wrap any DOM object in a jQuery object if you want to then use jQuery methods such as:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
var element2= document.createElement('a');
$(element1).append(element2);
```

**jQuery Allows you to Pass jQuery Objects OR DOM Elements as Arguments**

This last method adds one more slightly confusing aspect of all of this in that jQuery will usually let you pass either a DOM element or a jQuery object as an argument to a method.  So, in the above code snippet, it's OK that `element2` is just a DOM object event though we're using a jQuery method.  The `.append()` jQuery method will check to see if the object being appended is a DOM element or a jQuery object and will act appropriately.

Keep in mind that a jQuery object is just an object wrapper around an array of DOM elements with a whole bunch of useful methods attached to the jQuery object prototype.  So, you can conceptually think of a jQuery object as an array of 0 to n DOM elements and then methods just operate on the entire array of DOM elements that the jQuery object contains.

Comment: @slatniawadii - I'm just curious why you selected the three line answer with not near as much explanation of what is going on as the "best answer".  Earlier answers often get more upvotes just because they're seen by more people, but you should select carefully which answer you think is the "best answer".

Comment: because it was the first answer that solve my problem. 
thank you again for your explanation.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has `append`, native `DOM` uses `appendChild`:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
var element2= document.createElement('a');
element1.appendChild(element2);
```

Answer (score 5):

`append` is a jQuery method.

use `appendChild()` for DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

Because element1 is DOM object. You need to convert it to jquery object for using method `.append()`:

```
 $(element1).append(element2);
```